# How to store two polymorphic record types for getting best MySQL query performance when group by

Tags: mysql, group-by, polymorphism

I have two event types with some common fields. 
the first type has two more fields and the second one has 8 other fields.
max rate of the daily insert in the first one is about 200,000,000 records a day.
max rate of the daily insert in the second one is about 2000,000 records a day.

The question is: storing them in one table or splitting them in two tables (which needs to join later), which plan id better to have the best performance on group-by and count query,

event of type A:
caid, sid, coid, uid, timestamp, sub-type

event of type B:
caid, sid, coid,  uid, timestamp, sub-type, field1,.....,field9

what is needed: group by caid, sid, coid, uid and sub-type and select count of records for each.

Comment: why don't you test both scenarios?

Comment: I have not so big amount of data right now

Comment: Then generate some test data.